# Jquery table select row add class and get value select row

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

How I can addclass to selected row and get value selected row when keys click?

```js
$("#example tr").click(function() {
   $(this).addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected');
    value = $(this).find('td:first').html();
});

$(document).on('keydown', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (e.which == 38) {
        $('.selected').prev('tr').addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected');
        $('#testidyeni').text("test");
    } else if (e.which == 40) {
        $('.selected').next('tr').addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected');
    }
});
```

```html
<table class="table table-hover table-bordered table-scroll" id="example">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col"> Id </th>
            <th scope="col"> Aksesuar kateqoriya </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody  name="">
        <?php foreach ($testcek  as $olculer )   { ?> 
        <tr class="selected">
            <th scope="row"> <?php echo $olculer['id']; ?> </th>
            <td class="" value="<?php echo $olculer['id']; ?>"> <?php echo $olculer['aksesuaradi']; ?> </td>
        </tr>
        <?php } ?> 
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can move the arrow up and down function out of your row selection function. If there is no selected row then nothing will happen.

Please check the commented example below. I've added some checks to see if you're at the top or bottom of the table.

Let me know if you wanted something else

---

```js
$("#example tr").click(function() {

  // Exit early if already selected
  if ($(this).hasClass("selected")) {
     return;
  }

  // Remove selected class from any row
  $("#example tr.selected").removeClass("selected");

  // Assign selected class to clicked row
  $(this).addClass("selected");

  // Flag a selection change
  selectionChange();

});

// This is unchanged
$(document).on('keydown', function(e) {
  
  e.preventDefault();

  // Check if no row is selected
  if ($('tr.selected').length == 0 && (e.which == 38 || e.which == 40)) {

     // Select first row that is not the header
     $('tr:not(.header)').first().addClass("selected");
     selectionChange();

     // Leave the function early
     return;

  }

  // If arrow down clicked
  if (e.which == 38) {

    // Move selected row up one
    if ($('.selected').prev('tr').hasClass("header")) {

      console.log("Don't move to header row");

    } else {
      $('.selected').prev('tr').addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected');
      selectionChange();

    }

  } else if (e.which == 40) { // If arrow up

    // Move down a row
    if ($('.selected').next('tr').length == 0) {

      console.log("Do not move down if at bottom of table");

    } else {

      $('.selected').next('tr').addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected');
      selectionChange();
    }

  }


});


// Get value of selected row
function selectionChange() {

  v = $("tr.selected td:first").text();
  console.log(v);

}
```

```css
tr.selected {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-hover table-bordered table-scroll" id="example">

  <thead>

    <tr class="header">
      <th scope="col"> Id </th>
      <th scope="col"> Aksesuar kateqoriya </th>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Alpha</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Beta</td>
    </tr>

  </thead>
</table>
```

Comment: You only got the value when you clicked the row. I have now updated it to get the value after a key press as well. Also added some error checking so that it doesn't get the value from the header row, and will not re-run the `selectionChange()` function at the bottom of the table

Comment: It worked with the keys, but only after initially selecting one with a click. It now selects the first row when you first press a key if there hasn't already been a selected row.

Answer (score 1):

After setting `.selected` class to new row it's simply. Just use:

```
$('#example .selected td:first').text();
```